# How to resize logo when viewed on mobile

Tags: css, image, media-queries, responsive

I've been trying to enlarge the logo of our [site](http://www.furstenberglaw.com.au/) when viewed on mobile phone but no code seems to work. I've tried different versions of this but to no avail:

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
    .header-logo img {
        max-width: 50%;
        max-height: 50%;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to adjust further since Firebug seems to be displaying code for the desktop version. And I don't really want to change anything on desktop view. Just mobile.

Will appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the below changes in the css.

```
 .header-logo img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
   .header-logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('img_flowers.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At `max-width` of `360px` change style property for class `.custom-logo-link` as below,

```
@media screen and (max-width : 360px){
 .custom-logo-link {
    width: 50%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify only width, it will adjust height automatically.

```
.header-logo img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question, but are you sure max-width and max-height is what you want to change here? Those parameters just set the upper limit of how tall and wide the element can be.

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

Perhaps try one of these?

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .header-logo img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

or:

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .header-logo img {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
```